# Set new column names when applying functions to DataFrames with multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a function that receives a Pandas Series and returns a DataFrame containing some computations on the original series, and with different column names than the original Series name:

```
def vel_acc(series, n=1, change_names=False):
    vel = series.diff(n) / n
    acc = vel.diff()

    return pd.concat([vel, acc], axis=1)
```

And a second version that changes the output column names

```
def vel_acc_change_col_names(series, n=1):
    vel = series.diff(n) / n
    acc = vel.diff()

    vel.name = "VEL_{} ({})".format(str(n), series.name)
    acc.name="ACC_{} ({})".format(str(n), series.name)

    return pd.concat([vel, acc], axis=1)
```

I want to apply it to a big DataFrame, with a shape of ~(30000, 400). So I've written another function to use multiprocessing and spread the computations across the 8 cores of the CPU, based on [this](https://maxpowerwastaken.github.io/blog/multiprocessing-with-pandas/):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def process_Pandas_data(func, df, num_processes=None):

    if num_processes==None:
        num_processes = min(df.shape[1], cpu_count())

    with Pool(num_processes) as 
        seq = np.array_split(df, num_processes, axis=1)
        results_list = pool.map(func, seq)
        return pd.concat(results_list, axis=1)
```

I'm working with time-series price data, with the form

```
                      Close    High     Low    Open
Date                                               
2013-08-25 08:00:00  164.36  164.36  123.51  144.02
2013-08-25 09:00:00  127.40  165.75  127.40  164.36
2013-08-25 10:00:00  111.83  127.40  111.83  127.40
2013-08-25 11:00:00  121.35  121.35  111.83  111.83
2013-08-25 12:00:00  121.44  129.18  113.88  121.35
2013-08-25 13:00:00  133.10  133.10  113.80  121.44
2013-08-25 14:00:00  133.10  133.10  133.10  133.10
2013-08-25 15:00:00  121.47  133.10  107.66  133.10
2013-08-25 16:00:00  127.58  139.58  121.47  121.47
2013-08-25 17:00:00  151.22  164.52  127.58  127.58
```

When I make a function call like

```
process_Pandas_data(vel_acc, res.iloc[:, :4]).tail()
```

The result is

```
                    Close  Close   High   High    Low    Low   Open   Open
Date                                                                       
2013-08-25 13:00:00  11.66  11.57   3.92  -3.91  -0.08  -2.13   0.09  -9.43
2013-08-25 14:00:00   0.00 -11.66   0.00  -3.92  19.30  19.38  11.66  11.57
2013-08-25 15:00:00 -11.63 -11.63   0.00   0.00 -25.44 -44.74   0.00 -11.66
2013-08-25 16:00:00   6.11  17.74   6.48   6.48  13.81  39.25 -11.63 -11.63
2013-08-25 17:00:00  23.64  17.53  24.94  18.46   6.11  -7.70   6.11  17.74
```

The problem appears when I uncomment that two lines in vel_acc that set new names for the result of the function. I'd like to column names to be of the form VEL_1 (Close), ACC_1 (Close), .... When making a call like process_Pandas_data(vel_acc, res...) it returns the following error:

```
RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last)
RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xoel/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/xoel/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "<ipython-input-94-1a5f8ee15a6a>", line 5, in vel_acc
    vel.name = "VEL_{} ({})".format(str(n), series.name)
  File "/home/xoel/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3081, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-5d13d64e3941> in <module>()
----> 1 process_Pandas_data(vel_acc, res.iloc[:, :4]).tail()

<ipython-input-37-6e37653b2e53> in process_Pandas_data(func, df, num_processes)
     11         seq = np.array_split(df, num_partitions, axis=1)
     12 
---> 13         results_list = pool.map(func, seq)
     14 
     15         return pd.concat(results_list, axis=1)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    264         in a list that is returned.
    265         '''
--> 266         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    267 
    268     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    642             return self._value
    643         else:
--> 644             raise self._value
    645 
    646     def _set(self, i, obj):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
```

So, is there a way to pass functions to multiprocessing.Pool that operate on pandas.DataFrames to set new names for the output DataFrames?

Comment: In concurrent programming it is usually best to avoid using shared state as much as possible.  In this case you will have to open the dataset in the file if you want to use a dataframe, or pass the data to be worked on or some form of locking.

While `multiprocessing` does have locking, you will probably hit the same limits on `threading` where it will run slower.

Comment: I know, but in this case the results of a computation over a column don't affect the computation over other columns. The problem is just with the column names of the outputted DataFrame.

Comment: There seems to be some code missing: the line `results_list = pool.map(func,` is followed by a return statement.

Comment: Are you sure that the objects that you are passing to each worker are in fact `Series` objects as you expect? The error message implies that they might rather be `DataFrame` objects. I don't think this error has anything to do with multiprocessing itself.

Comment: @myrtlecat thanks, there was a word missing, I've just corrected it. That line is `results_list = pool.map(func, seq)`

Comment: NOTE: as I can't edit my above comment, let me state my error to avoid the spreadk of misinformation. I thought that  Dataframes (vs Series) was not pickle safe, but I was incorrect.  Sorry an attempt at being terse failed here. My original assumption was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `np.array_split(df, num_processes, axis=1)` creates a list of `DataFrame` objects, not `Series` objects. `DataFrame` objects don't have a `name` attribute, which is why you get the `AttributeError`.

You should change your definition of `seq` to ensure that it contains instances of `Series`, for example you could do:

```
seq = [df[column_name] for column_name in df]
```

This should avoid the `AttributeError`.